# Mongobee stuck several minutes before to quit

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongobee

I'm currently using mongobee to update a mongoDB database.
An update can take up to a few minutes however it seems that the real behaviour of mongobee itself only lasts for a few seconds and after that the java process stay stuck for a few minutes before to shut.

```
2020-10-13 17:32:53.791  INFO 1 --- [mongo] o.m.d.cluster                                      : Setting max set version to 4 from replica set primary XXXXXXXXX
2020-10-13 17:32:53.791  INFO 1 --- [mongo] o.m.d.cluster                                      : Discovered replica set primary XXXXXXXXX
2020-10-13 17:32:54.889  INFO 1 --- [imer-1-thread-1] o.m.d.connection                         : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:18352}] to XXXXXXXXX
2020-10-13 17:32:55.191  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.g.m.Mongobee                           : Mongobee acquired process lock, starting the data migration sequence..
2020-10-13 17:32:55.508  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.r.Reflections                          : Reflections took 200 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 1 keys and 1 values
2020-10-13 17:32:55.691  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.g.m.Mongobee                           : Mongobee is releasing process lock.
2020-10-13 17:32:55.698  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.g.m.Mongobee                           : Mongobee has finished his job.
2020-10-13T17:35:37,089 TECHNICAL INFO myapplication {o.s.b.StartupInfoLogger} Started MyApplication in 28.81 seconds (JVM running for 36.744)
```

After that, the java process still works for a few minutes before to end without any further log.

According to the log, Mongobee has finished his job at 17:35:37, so I don't understand why I'm stuck for maybe 5 minutes before it stops.

Is it an expected behaviour ? Does springboot/mongobee have a parameter like maybe a "session idle time" to be respected before to leave the connexion ?

Comment: I would try increasing the log level to `TRACE` to see if you can determine what else is happening during that time.

Comment: Yes, we obtain a loop of "checking status of mymongodbcluster:XXX" and the answer state=CONNECTED".

2020-10-15T17:06:07,248 TECHNICAL       DEBUG   mymongobee         {c.m.d.l.SLF4JLogger}   Sending command '{ "ismaster" : 1, "$db" : "workdatabase", "$clusterTime" : { "clusterTime" : { "$timestamp" : { "t" : 1602774359, "i" : 1 } }, "signature" : { "hash" : { "$binary" : { "base64" : "XXXXXXXXXXXXX", "subType" : "00" } }, "keyId" : XXXXXXX } } }' with request id 222 to database working on connection [connectionId{localValue:9, serverValue:89816}] to server mymongodbcluster.